# Visual Studio 2022 Build Fail: "ResolveManifestFiles", CultureNotFoundException

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2022, c#-10.0

I just tried building my old project in vs2019 to newer vs2022 but getting following error and unable to build it.

Can somebody suggest what can be done to resolve the issue?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ResolveManifestFiles" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
v4.0_12.0.0.0_de_89845dcd8080cc91 is an invalid culture identifier.
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.GetItemCulture(ITaskItem item)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.GetOutputAssemblies(List`1 publishInfos, List`1 assemblyList)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.GetOutputAssembliesAndSatellites(List`1 assemblyPublishInfos, List`1 satellitePublishInfos)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Kings ERP
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why, but if you remove "Enable ClickOnce security settings" it'll work.

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot Mario, i wasted more then a week by removing many things from my vs2019 project and build it adding each item one by one. i asked question late on stackoverflow and saw result on 1st december 2021 by you. just removing Enable ClickOnce security settings did the magic

Comment: As per Mario's answer: more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-enable-clickonce-security-settings?view=vs-2022

Comment: Disabling work for a short moment; but in fact, we need ClickOnce, so there can only be a workaround, not a solution.
Is there any other solution out there?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and finally I found the problematic code in my solution.

I have 198 Projects in my solution, in 197 of them is the line
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
disabled: //[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
or the line does not exist at all
inside the Assembly.cs.

But in one of my (base) projects I found this:
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")]

After I changed it to: //[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")]
everything works fine.