# Visual Studio 2022 Build Fail: "ResolveManifestFiles", CultureNotFoundException ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am asking a follow-up question to the question asked here:

[Visual Studio 2022 Build Fail: "ResolveManifestFiles", CultureNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908135/visual-studio-2022-build-fail-resolvemanifestfiles-culturenotfoundexception)

One response was to uncheck the "Enable ClickOnce security settings" box.
My question then is:
How do you publish your clickonce application? Every time I go to do so, that checkbox is re-checked and will not compile.

Thanks, I hope I did this right, I am still trying to understand the complexities of this great and very informative community.

Comment: See [ Assembly.cs AssemblyCulture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70861654/9007215)

Comment: Thanks Frank! Unfortunately this solution did not work for me though. I removed all references to assembly: AssemblyCulture and it would still not compile.